# Hash appear in url when reload a page in vue-router history mode

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, vue-router

I'm working on laravel 5.5+SPA project. Hash appear in every route when I reload the page: https://dev.pramsystem.com/#/. My web Server Configuration is as recommended in https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html. I'm worry, I cant solve this problem. I have no ideas about this strange "#".

*My route.js file:*

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.use(VueRouter);
let routes = [
{
    path: '/',
    component: require('./views/Home.vue')
},
{
   path: '/history',
   component: require('./views/History.vue')
},
{
   path: '/options',
   component: require('./views/Options.vue')
},
{
   path: '/manageProduct/:id',
   name: 'manageProduct',
   component: require('./views/ManageProduct.vue'),
   props: true
}

];

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes,
    scrollBehavior: function(to, from, savedPosition) {
        if (to.hash) {
            return {selector: to.hash}
        } else {
            return { x: 0, y: 0 }
        }
    },

});


export default router
```

*My web.php file:*

```
Route::put('products/productNote/{product}',
'ProductController@updateProductNote');
Route::post('/file', 'ProductController@uploadFile');
Route::get('/days', 'ProductController@getDays');
Route::get('/profit', 'ProductController@getProfit');
Route::get('/export', 'ProductController@export');
Route::get('/products/chart', 'ProductController@chart');
Route::get('/products/{date?}', 'ProductController@index');
Route::get('/products/{product}/edit/{flag?}', 'ProductController@edit');
Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');

Route::resource('goal', 'GoalController');

Route::resource('employee', 'EmployeeController');

Route::resource('vendor', 'VendorController');

Route::patch('/fee/{product}', 'ProductController@feeRecalculate');

Route::any('{all}', function () {
    return view('index');
})->where(['all' => '.*']);
```

*app.js*:

```
 require('./bootstrap');
 window.Vue = require('vue');
 import Vue from 'vue';
 /* Vuex */
 import Vuex from 'vuex';
 Vue.use(Vuex);
 import store from './store';
 /* VueRouter */
 import router from './routes';
 /* VueSweetAlert */
import VueSweetAlert from 'vue-sweetalert'
Vue.use(VueSweetAlert);
window.moment = require('moment');

/* Event Bus */
export const Bus = new Vue();

Vue.component('Goal', require('./components/Goal.vue'));
Vue.component('ProfitDay', require('./components/ProfitDay.vue'));

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    store,
    created () {
        this.$store.dispatch('loadData');
},
});
```

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Only thing I see here is that you can solve and you are worried. But not exactly where you are stuck. Please update your question with details of what you have tried or where you are failing.

Comment: Deal was in double init of vue router. I found it in some component.